# Space travel energy limitations

Tags: physics, space, space-travel

For long distance space travel (between galaxies etc), I am trying to work out whether the amount of mass being transported is of significance, or is only the amount of drag important?

For an example, what about transporting 1000 tonnes mass of mass from one end of the Milk Way to the other.

Comment: Hello Max888 , it really depends on a few factors - could you tell us more about the specific circumstances? We need a specific problem presented to us to solve whereas this question is more the start of a conversation. Take the [tour] and then read-up in the [help] about how we work and [ask]. I'm voting to put on hold so you can [edit] before unhelpful answers are posted, then your question can be re-opened.

Comment: Hi Max888, when you ask about drag and space travel?  Can you expand on your assumptions?  Drag requires an atmosphere, and space is a vacuum.  I imagine you are focusing on specific aspects of space travel like launch or reentry -- that take place in a planet's atmosphere.  Please add details about the scenarios you are working on.

Comment: @EDL I've updated the question to clarify that I am interested in very long distance travel. In this case the drag caused by the particles in space might be significant, even though the density is of course far lower than earth's atmosphere (I remember reading this somewhere but can't find a source I'm afraid).

Comment: @BLT-Bub I've added an example, does this help?

Comment: The "drag caused by the particles in space" is not significant, unless the ship is travelling at very high speed, as in a considerable fraction of the speed of light; and in that case it is not so much the "drag" which is important as the protection against particles hitting the ship. For all practical purposes, space is a vacuum.